# ERROR in bin/magento dev:urn-catalog:generate .idea/misc.xml

Tags: magento2, module, error, magentomodule, module-development

I am getting File ".idea/misc.xml" cannot be opened Warning!fopen(.idea/misc.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  while trying to generate urn AND YES the folder ./idea does exist so just creating again didn't work

[image]

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Please check you have permission to write into `.idea` directory and check permissions for `misc.xml` inside as well. You can try to remove `.idea/misc.xml` and run command again or you can run the command and specify another one place and after move generated file into `.idea/misc.xml`.

Comment: Should the original reference be ./idea........  ?  This is more common than .idea in most of what I have observed.

Comment: @WilsonHauck no its .idea

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk Yes I have the permissions to write into misc.xml.I tried also to run the command to another path where i granted all permissions and i still get the same error failed to open stream: No such file or directory ...

Comment: Please update with full error when you try to use with parameter like `~/idea-misc.xml`.